# Chrome wouldn't work without Burp Proxy

Tags: google-chrome

I have setup my Burp Proxy in Google Chrome using FroxyProxy extension. Now, unless I use the Burp Proxy I am not able to access internet from the browser even when I have Disabled FroxyProxy.

[image: Google Chrome when FroxyProxy disabled]

Comment: Looks like Chrome still wants to use a proxy. Why do you need the extension anyways? Chrome has command line options for proxy. Did you setup a system wide proxy? if so then you wont get any connection as long as BurpProxy is not running. https://portswigger.net/burp/documentation/desktop/external-browser-config/browser-config-chrome-windows

Comment: Burp (even the Community Edition)has an in built browser which you access from tab Proxy > Open browser. Use that and you won't need to worry about any proxy settings on your main Chrome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after you have set up traffic proxying through Burp Suite, each time you start your browser, it tries to connect to said proxy (127.1:8080 by default). But when Burp is down, the proxy server is also down, and any attempt to establish connection to a website results in timeout. Thus your connection does not get established and effectively you get no Internet.
**The solution** is to disable Proxy usage in your extension's settings every time you do not want to start Burp alongside your browser.
Alternatively you can use Burp's inbuilt Chromium browser so you do not have to change your proxy settings each time.